# CakePHP 2.6 flash messages not showing

Tags: php, authentication, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, flash-message

Based on a condition in jsonresponse() function from JobsController, I want to logout user and send them to login page with a flash message Invalid user.

**jsonresponse($data)**

```
if($data['status'] == '0'){
    $this->Session->setFlash(__(INVALID_USERS_CREDENTIALS),'default', array('class' => 'error-flash-msg'));
        return $this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());
}
```

Now it is redirecting to login page, but flash message is not showing.

In **Loginlayout**

```
 <div style="padding-left:12%">
        <?php echo $this->Session->flash(); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="loginbox">
        <?php echo $this->fetch('content');?>
    </div>
</body>
```

what is the issue here, when I goto login page and enter invalid credentials, it show me flash message. But what is problem in above case...!
Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: can you show us the result of `debug($_SESSION)` on your `view`

Comment: It is showing nothing..!

Comment: But before redirecting ,If I debug($_SESSION) in controller, It is showing message data in in controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to logout before setting the session flash message because `logout()` destroys the session content

```
if($data['status'] == '0'){
    $this->Auth->logout()
    $this->Session->setFlash(__(INVALID_USERS_CREDENTIALS),'default', array('class' => 'error-flash-msg'));
    return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
}
```

Or, to keep the redirection url as you did it :

```
if($data['status'] == '0'){
    $redirectUrl = $this->Auth->logout()
    $this->Session->setFlash(__(INVALID_USERS_CREDENTIALS),'default', array('class' => 'error-flash-msg'));
    return $this->redirect($redirectUrl);
}
```